# javascript - How to split string to object array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to split a String that I send through AJAX to Array for use in Google Charts.

```
    var arr = dataChart.split('|@|');

    arr = Object.values(arr);
    console.log(arr);
    data.addRows([
        arr
    ]);
```

My string (dataChart) is something like this:

```
['First level', null, 0]|@|['Inside first level', 'First level', 1000]|@| ['Second level', null, 0]|@|['Inside second level', 'Second level', 1000]
```

I expect the output to be:

> Object 0: First level, null, 0
>
> Object 1: Inside first level, First level, 1000
>
> [...]

Expected result

[image: Expected result]

Comment: It looks like you want to convert an array to a key-value object with keys being "Object n"? (not split a string)

Comment: String must be something like "asdasd asd" or \`asdasdas asdsa\`, but in your example i see array. And what the output, what this mean?

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried and maybe why it didn't work.

Comment: How did you obtain the string, how does it look when sent via the AJAX call. Is it exactly as stated: `"['First level', null, 0], ['Inside first level', 'First level', 1000], ['Second level', null, 0], ['Inside second level', 'Second level', 1000]"`?

Comment: @Dominic I add a image with expected result. I edited the code too

Comment: @VadimHulevich My string looks like array, but i need array object. The expected result is added. I edited the code too

Comment: @Juan What I obtain is the string like this via AJAX, and I need a array like the image I added. I edited the code too

Comment: Does the string you receive contain the `|@|` between the arrays?

Comment: @Juan It can be |@| or just a coma {,}, I use |@| because I have comas into the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I can think of is to try the following:

```
JSON.parse(`[${variable name that contains the string}]`)
```

That might cause an issue if the string actually contains apostrophes (`'`) for the strings and not double quotes (`"`).

To solve this you could replace with regex to replace all single quote strings with double quote strings:

```
str.replace(/\['/g, "[\"")
   .replace(/',/g, "\",")
   .replace(/, ?'/g, ",\"")
   .replace(/'\]/g, "\"]")
```

Alternatively, you can just use `str.replace(/'/g, "\"")` but that would replace any apostrophes in the strings themselves as well, for example `'Jake's car'` would become `"Jake"s car"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the splitted array and use eval

```js
var dataChar = "['First level', null, 0]|@|['Inside first level', 'First level', 1000]|@| ['Second level', null, 0]|@|['Inside second level', 'Second level', 1000]";
     var arr = dataChar.split('|@|').map(function(row){return eval(row);});
     arr = Object.values(arr);
     console.log(arr);
```